# 499.28999999999996 -> 499.28 How do I remove a decimal point without rounding it?

Tags: swift

When you have the code below,

The result should be 499.28

How do I remove a decimal point without rounding it?

```
var tmp:Double = 499.28999999999996
print(tmp.someFunction()) //-> 499.28 String
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Float80`for more precision :

```
var tmp: Float80 = 499.28999999999996

let times100 = tmp * 100

let noFraction =  times100 - times100.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)

tmp = noFraction/100

print(tmp)   //499.28
```

Comment: @Albert Not my computer. Do try it in a playground

Comment: @Albert Have you changed the type to `Float80` ?

Comment: Good~ . Thanks. Result with Float80 is 499.28

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `floor()` function with some scaling to achieve the result you want:

```
var tmp:Double = 499.28999999999996
floor(tmp * 100) / 100 //returns 499.28
```

Comment: This would give the wrong result for negative numbers

Comment: print(floor(tmp * 100) / 100) => result 499.29

Comment: Good point. You could get around this by branching if the number is negative, operating on the abs() of the value, then multiplying by -1. Not sure I like that answer though.

Comment: I suggest adding an example with a negative number to your question to avoid getting this same answer more times.

Comment: Eric M. Johnson - Thanks